# Switching Antlr lexer modes from parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How to control switching `Antlr` lexer modes from parser actions?
I extended the generated Parser and Lexer so I can call `pushMode` and `popMode` from parser witch in turn call suitable `pushMode` and `popMode` of lexer but with no effect. Is there any thing I can do to activate this functionality?

Comment: I suspect by the time the parser-rules are being hit, the lexer has already gone to work making tokens past the point where you want the switch-over to occur... Is it possible to determine the switch-over points using *only* lexer rules? If not, perhaps there is some way to re-wind the lexer's token stream and discard the tokens you don't trust.

Answer (score 8):

Your lexer should be written such that the input can be completely tokenized before the parser is even created. Even though the token stream is lazily filled, ANTLR 4 is not guaranteed to correctly parse the input if your lexer does not meet this requirement.